# How to turn off cache for upsell and related product section?

Tags: magento, caching

In Magento I have turned on the cache and on the products view page there are two sections: upsell and related products. When I refresh the page, the products in these two sections differ with configure products as from admin. Can any one help me how to turn off cache for this two blocks, upsell and related?

Comment: what version of Magento?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off particular block for cache. Here is very good document to turn off cache for block just find your upsell and related block in Magento with path hint

Please refer http://www.magikcommerce.com/blog/how-to-turn-off-cache-for-an-individual-block-in-magento/.

Answer (score 0):

In the particular XML file. Say catalog.xml

In that for particular reference block In that block set the action of cache limit to null

Example of catalog.xml

```
<reference name="right">
    <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.product.cat.related" as="related_cat" template="catalog/navigation/list_cat.phtml" after="-" >
        <action method="unsetData"><key>cache_lifetime</key></action>
        <action method="unsetData"><key>cache_tags</key></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```